# How to create a table with flexible columns based on variables control in R?

Tags: r

I want to create a tale like:

```
1 1 6 6 10 10 ...
2 2 7 7 11 11 ... 
3 3 8 8 12 12 ...
4 4 9 9 13 13 ...
5 5     14 14 ...
        15 15 ...
```

I want to  use  variables:

n (repeat) and m(total number of columns) and k(k=the prior columns's end number+1,for example: 6=5+1, and 10=9+1), and different number length of row
to create a table.

I know I can use like:

```
rep(list(1:5,6:9,10:15), each = 2)),
```

but how to make them as parameters using a general expression to list list(1:5,6:9,10:15,..use n,m,k expression...).

I tried to use loop for (i in 1:m) etc.. but cannot work it out
finally I want a sequence by using unlist(): 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6......)
Many thanks.

Comment: You cannot have columns with unequal length in a dataframe. Also how do you decide that the first list should go from 1 to 5 and not 1 to 6 or 7 etc?

Comment: I can add other variables to control the now's length. Is there any way to create unequal length table or list()? in the end, I can use unlist() to generate a sequence: 1.2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the code below can help

```
len <- c(5,4,6)
res <- unlist(unname(rep(split(1:sum(len),
                               findInterval(1:sum(len),cumsum(len)+1)),
                         each = 2)))
```

which gives

```
> res
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, something like this would be helpful.

```
#Number of times to repeat
r <- 2
#Length of each sequence
len <- c(5, 4, 6)
#Get the end of the sequence
end <- cumsum(Glen)
#Calculate the start of each sequence
start <- c(1, end[-length(end)] + 1)

#Create a sequence of start and end and repeat it r times
Map(function(x, y) rep(seq(x, y), r), start, end)
#[[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5

#[[2]]
#[1] 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9

#[[3]]
# [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

You could `unlist` to get it as one vector.

```
unlist(Map(function(x, y) rep(seq(x, y), r), start, end))
```